# How to automate a command in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, input, parameters, command

Hi I have a batch file named megacmd2.bat looking like this:

```
@rem
@rem Megatools command line with appropriate paths set
@rem
@echo Megatools Shell
@set PATH=%CD%;%PATH%
@cmd
```

And this is the input I wish the batch to run automatically in stead of manually once it is launched:

```
megals /Root --username username@email.domain --password password
megamkdir /Root/testmake2 --username username@email.domain --password password
```

But I have no Idea how or even where I should enter these lines without disturbing the rest of the batch file. In first instance I tried launching the .bat file by another bat file passing along these commands, but that did not work.

Now I tried learning the specifics for the batch scripting to incorporate this succesfully, whilst looking at countless of examples reaching the same goal. But I can't seem to get the syntax right for this specific problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "run automatically instead of manually once it is launched?" How is putting the `megals` and `megamkdir` lines at the bottom of the script not what you want?

Comment: With that I mean that once megacmd2.bat is opened, the file automatically executes those two commands, rather waiting for the user to manually type those in the command screen after which he or she must press enter.  
  
As far as I am concerned, that is exactly what I want, but I tried putting those two commands at the end of the batch script, and running it but they are not executed.  

I assume that is because I do not follow the way a batch script accepts and executes commands without requiring user action.

Comment: That should work perfectly; try putting `start "" ` in front of both commands.

Comment: I just did, I tried;

    `start "" megals /Root --username username@email.domain --password password`

But it will not execute anything, might it be because inherently to the code that was already in there, that it passes along control to a different module before coming to my commands, where in that other module, it waits for the user input, meaning the commands in my batch aren't even reached?

Ps. It's driving me mad, sorry for the offtopic, but in the help it says, "End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak:" and I do, but the formatting does not apply, I apologize.

Comment: Delete the `@cmd` command.

Comment: You sir, are my hero! 

Deleting the `@cmd` command, and then again deleting the `start ""` in front of the commands, did the trick! So basically the combination of your first suggestion and last, yielded succes!

So the above script, -the `@cmd` with the pure simple commands each in a new line worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `@cmd` is opening a new instance of the command prompt, which does not receive any further commands from the batch script once it has been opened. Delete it, and then simply put your commands at the end of the script.

Also, you can use `@echo off` so that you don't need to put `@` at the start of each line.

```
@echo off
rem
rem Megatools command line with appropriate paths set
rem
echo Megatools Shell
set PATH=%CD%;%PATH%
megals /Root --username username@email.domain --password password
megamkdir /Root/testmake2 --username username@email.domain --password password
```